# How to Send A Consecutive Request by URL : Python-request

Tags: python, request

I am learning python-request step by step to build a url queries to en.wiktionary.org

I need to build a function that sequentially fetch the url data based on pre-defined key:value dictionary:

```
Word_Set = {'key1': 'region', 'key2': reason}
```

If I put something like this:

```
r = requests.get('http://en.wiktionary.org', params=Word_Set)
```

What I desire to get is like this:

```
print(r.url)
http://en.wiktionary.org/region
http://en.wiktionary.org/reason
```

Any hint how to do this using Python3 and requrests module in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a request per word, you can't do it all in one. Simplest way in this case is to loop over the values in your dictionary:

```
Word_Set = {'key1': 'region', 'key2': 'reason'}
for word in Word_Set.values():
    r = requests.get('http://en.wiktionary.org/{}'.format(word))
    print(r.url)
```

Comment: beautifully well working resulting in cuttie hyperlinks like following :
https://en.wiktionary.org/region
https://en.wiktionary.org/reason

Comment: How could I recall the first value from pre-defined dictionary? like I want to do something like this (but which is working really) :
Word_Set.values()[0] which returns 'region'

Comment: @Beverlie are you using the keys (key1, key2) for anything? If not just make it a straight list of words and you can index it like you have there `words = ['region', 'reason']`and then to get the first word `words[0]`. Any reason you are using a dictionary?

Comment: Because I read them from the ods files. But I think your version is better. Will use that way.